# TS error: "Cannot find name 'T' how to pass the generic?

Tags: typescript, recompose

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/recompose in my project

I need to pass a generic "T" to Table, how to change the type signature so `compose<Props<T>, CompProps<T>>` will be satisfied?

I have tried with no success:

`export const Table<T> = ..`.

```
export const Table = compose<Props<T>, CompProps<T>>(
  setDisplayName('Grid'),
  injectSheet(styles)
)(TableComp);
```

Error I am receving is:

```
"Cannot find name 'T'
```

Comment: What should `T` be? There is no type `T` in your code.

Comment: You have to create `type Table<T> = ...` and declare variable like `export const Table: T = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no type use `any`:

```
export const Table = compose<Props<any>, CompProps<any>>(
  setDisplayName('Grid'),
  injectSheet(styles)
)(TableComp);
```

Edit: Ok with keeping type safety

```
export const Table<T> = compose<Props<T>, CompProps<T>>(
  setDisplayName('Grid'),
  injectSheet(styles)
)(TableComp);
```

Comment: I lose type safety in this way